# how to compare address with same customerno in same table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a SQL Slowly changing dimension table of customer which has their all the changes.
for e.g

```
 customerno           name        address              phone    CrrentRecord 
    00001              abc         72 fulton drive       123             Y
    00001              abc         72 fulton drive       321             N
    00001              abc         69 charter dive       111             N
    00002              xyz         62 iak grove way      111             Y
    00002              xyz         63 ikea drive         222             N
    00003              pqr         port capital dr       369             Y
    00003              pqr         port capital dr1      369             N
```

I want to know which customer has change their address.

I've also tried Lead and Lag function but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
select customerno
from YourTable
group by customerno
having count(distinct [address]) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you customers who have changed their address.

Without a desired results, hard to say what additional info is needed

```
Select customerno
 From  YourTable
 Group By customerno
 Having min(address)<>max(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check customer with non current records, try this

```
select customerno
from YourTable
group by customerno
having count(distinct [CrrentRecord]) > 1
```

Comment: Not sure currentrecord would do the trick.  Let's assume there was no record for 69 charter dive

Comment: @John it would still work, as there are still 2 records, one Y and another N. As it seems that's the flag he is using to identify the latest record

Comment: But still the same address

Comment: But different phone number. He wants to know which customer made changes, any change, that's was I'm understanding anyway, I could be wrong

Comment: OK I know he said address, but I'm kinda reading between the lines here.

Comment: You may be right... I just have a different read.  Without desired results, we're both guessing  :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I just care about address... since it is a slowly changing dimension table it tracks all the changes of customer weather its a address change ph change name change. But I just wanted to find which customers are changes their address.